The definitions is different between the GA4 interface and the Google Analytics Data API
Issue
There is a discrepancy in the definitions of "New and Returning" visitors between the GA4 interface and the Google analytics DataAPI, causing the numbers to not match.
Questions
The definitions is different between the GA4 interface and the Google Analytics Data API. Is it possible to calculate same metrics with the GA4 interface using the Google Analytics Data API?
Code
import
from google.api_core.exceptions import GoogleAPICallError, InvalidArgument
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    DateRange,
    Dimension,
    Metric,
    RunReportRequest,
    OrderBy
)
from google.api_core.retry import Retry

Example of data fetch
request = RunReportRequest(
                property=f"properties/{property_id}",
                dimensions=[
                    Dimension(name="date"),
                    Dimension(name="userAgeBracket"),
                    Dimension(name="newVsReturning")
                   
                ],
                metrics=[
                   Metric(name="activeUsers"), 
                    Metric(name="newUsers"),
                    Metric(name="sessions"), 
                    Metric(name="screenPageViews"),
                    Metric(name="screenPageViewsPerSession"), 
                    Metric(name="averageSessionDuration"), 
                    Metric(name="conversions"), 
                    Metric(name="sessionConversionRate"), 
                    Metric(name="userConversionRate"),
                ],
            date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date=arg.start, end_date=arg.end)],
            )
    retry_policy = Retry(initial=1.0, maximum=10.0, multiplier=2.0, deadline=30.0)
    try:
        response = client.run_report(request=request, retry=retry_policy)
    except InvalidArgument as e:
        print(f"Invalid request: {e}")
        return [],e.args
    except GoogleAPICallError as e:
        print(f"API call error: {e}")
        return [],e.args
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return [],e.args

I want to make sure there is a way or not. Either way is fine for me. Just need to make sure.
